# Format number to last two decimals

Tags: javascript, node.js, numbers

I am trying to format numbers in JS to last two decimal.

For example 10100 becomes 101.00 -  606000 becomes 6,060.00 - 7600 becomes 76.00 and so on.

I have tried num.toFixed(2) but that was not of help. I also tried `Number(10100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {minimumFractionDigits: 0})` but I end up with 10.100 so it seems off by one decimal.

Answer (score 0):

So

```
num.toFixed(2)
```

What its doing its formatting, 
Which would be 10.123 -> 10.12

what you should do is divide number by 100.

```
var number = 10100
number = number / 100
```

would be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The most simplified way:

```
output = (number/100).toFixed(2)
```

And the complex way:

```
var c = 7383884
a = c.toString()
var output = parseFloat([a.slice(0, -2), ".",a.slice(-2)].join(''))

document.write(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will approach this problem by using the help of *strings*.

Strings can be easily manipulated based on our requirements and then can be converted back to numbers. So, the solution goes like this

1. Convert the number to string
2. Manipulate the string to add a decimal before last two character
3. Convert the string back to number

```js
const formatNumberToLastTwoDecimal = (number) => {
  // Convert the number to String
  const inputNumAsStr = number.toString();
  // Manipulate the string and add decimal before two char
  const updatedStr = `${inputNumAsStr.slice(0, -2)}.${inputNumAsStr.slice(-2)}`;
  // Return by converting the string to number again
  // Fix by 2 to stop parseFloat() from stripping zeroes to right of decimal
  return new Number(parseFloat(updatedStr)).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(formatNumberToLastTwoDecimal(606000));
```